# Word document downloaded with window.open doesn't open (IE7/IE8)

Tags: javascript, ssl, ms-word

We're having a problem getting Word documents to download in IE7/IE8 using window.open calls.  This problem is currently only happening in our production environment with SSL enabled - our test environment is working correctly but does NOT have SSL enabled.  Both environments are running IIS6 and use integrated authentication.

The javascript is pretty simple:

```
    function OpenNewWindow(sURL, sName, sHeight, sWidth)
{
    var sFeatures = "top=40,left=190,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=no";
    sFeatures = "width=" + sWidth + ",height=" + sHeight + "," + sFeatures;

    var newWindow = window.open(sURL, sName, sFeatures);
    newWindow.focus();
}
```

The above function is being passed relative paths, and the page itself (an ASP.NET page) is pre-formatted HTML.  The code-behind for the page is setting the content type to "application/msword" and allows ASP.NET to write the contents of the page to the output stream.

When the above function is called, a new window is created and then immediately closes without any errors or prompts.  As far as I can tell (using Fiddler) caching is enabled and HTTP compression is NOT enabled.  The actual document content is returned, but there seems to be some kind of disconnect between IE and Word.

An oddity I've noticed are that in test there is an negotiate challenge put out and responded to with a Kerberos ticket while in production no challenge/response occurs (although one does occur on the opening page and the response is NTLM).  Addtionally, a direct link to the page (Word document) in question DOES work correctly in both environments.  Finally, unchecking the "Confirm open after download" option for the .DOC file type allows the document to be successfully opened (but is NOT a solution we are willing to pursue for 2000+ employees).

I know this is limited information and I may need to add more details, but I've spent the better part of a day searching/testing and do not feel any closer to resolving this problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Headers for both environments:

**TEST request (works correctly, no SSL)**
GET /webapps/gfcse/CSEPrint.aspx?mode=ReadOnly&sSurveyId=3060 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
UA-CPU: x86
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)
Host: pc55516svma
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=elto5pakakvepbju42w24eef
Authorization: Negotiate [snip]

**TEST response**
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 26458
Content-Type: application/msword; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.6421
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate [snip]
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Date: Thu, 08 Jul 2010 15:14:26 GMT

[document content]

**PRODUCTION request (does NOT work, SSL enabled)**
GET /gfcse/CSEPrint.aspx?mode=ReadOnly&sSurveyId=3582 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
UA-CPU: x86
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)
Host: intranet.gfnet.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=h2xw0ebweb4e2455iab1tvbf

**PRODUCTION response**
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 26438
Content-Type: application/msword; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.6219
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Date: Thu, 08 Jul 2010 15:07:41 GMT

[document content]

Comment: @user387121 I've never used ASP..but I seriously doubt it has anything to do with javascript and has more to do with the headers that are being sent: have you seen these pages:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431
http://www.robpoyntz.com/blog/?p=245
(is php but the header stuff should still apply).

Comment: I have seen the Microsoft KB article before but did not see tine PHP-oriented one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, as it turns out, has nothing to do with the headers but rather what we were attempting to do via javascript - automatically downloading files.

Because our test and production environments are in different security zones there were different settings affecting the file downloads (specifically the "automatic prompting for file downloads").  Since we were trying to download files via javascript in a zone that had the information bar enabled, the browser was doing what it is supposed to.  There are a few different ways to address this (i.e. group policy, downloa

A similar problem is solved in this thread:  [IE7 issue - cannot download streamed file when Automatic prompting for file downloads is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612790/ie7-issue-cannot-download-streamed-file-when-automatic-prompting-for-file-downl)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find this isn't really an issue to do with javascript, more an IE and HTTP headers issue. We had a similar issue trying to open csv files different combinations of headers will work correctly others wont.I cant remeber which ones are needed, these are what we ended up having to set

note this is in php but you should be able to translate to .net

```
setHeader("Expires", gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT")
setHeader("Last-Modified",  gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT")
setHeader("Cache-Control", "", true)
setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $filenameToReturn)
setHeader('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream')
setHeader("Content-length", sprintf('%d', filesize($this->view->filename)));
```

Now that I think about the issues is with the Cache-Control header, and it must be empty

Comment: In the above the :
setHeader("Cache-Control", "", true)
is basically forcing the Cache-Control to be empty using zend framework, since in php when sessions are used it automatically sets Cache-Control: no-cache, so need to override and set it to empty value. Probably not an issue in asp.net

Comment: I'd buy the "not a javascript issue" response if the problem weren't ONLY happening when downloading the file via window.open.  Since the headers between the two environments are virtually the same (the only notable difference being the absence of the authorization challenge/response in production) and the document is actually getting returned, I'm wondering why there is a difference between using window.open and an anchor element.

The problem seems to be what IE does with the document once it's downloaded, and the normal solutions to fixing the "document not being cached" issue don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.Web.HttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) to force the files to be downloaded from the users' browser.

```
Protected Sub btnDownloadMe_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnDownloadMe.Click



    Dim filename As String = "demo.docx"

    'For old version of MS Word use application/msword

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", filename))
    Response.[End]()


End Sub
```

Comment: Changing the content disposition to attachment is something that crossed my mind but I ran out of time to try it out yesterday.  I'll probably give this a try today and see what happens ;)